# Dbus: Terminate not working on other user

Tags: linux, permissions, login, session, d-bus

I'm new with dbus(Using Ubuntu 14.04, Unity). So I'm logged with user A, create process as user B and that process creates session for user B, now I want to use dbus messages to shut down session from that process for user B. I want my process to work on every desktop env. So I have download tool called `d-feet`, and started to play with it, I've noticed that everytime session is created in system `/org/freedesktop/User/1002` is added(1002 is UID for user B) in `org.freedesktop.login1`. 
So I tried to launch: 
`sudo dbus-send --type=method_call --print-reply --system --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1/user/1000 org.freedesktop.login1.User.Terminate`
 
But it gives me error saying `Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownObject: Unknown user`, I used `ctr+alt+f1` login in as user B, launched `startx` and from user A-s desktop I used same command, it gives error saying `'GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownObject: Permission Denied'` But this time it works(shuts downs session). I'm little lost. Hope you can help. Thanks.